# Why my mesh isn't moving with my armature?

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

[image]

so, I am creating a cel-shaded RPG, and I created this low poly character for now so I can get the base animations and stuff done in unity.

I rigged the character following a tutorial by Royal skies LLC on youtube, and the armature does not move with the mesh. can someone please tell me how to fix this? also it is worth mentioning that I am new to blender but pretty comfortable with unity.

Comment: Not sure if you only confused it, just saying: The armature controls the mesh, and the mesh moves with the armature, not vice versa. Can you add more info on how you bound the armature to the mesh? (Ctrl+P, With Automatic Weights?) and have you check the deformation in Pose mode? (select the armature and switch to Pose mode)

Comment: sorry, I accidentally switched them around in the desc. lol.

so all of the bones are in deformation mode, and I dont know about the weights. how do I check that?

 edit: NVM. Character mesh is parented to the armature and set to automatic weight now. lol

Comment: Got it figured out thanks!

Comment: I was an idiot and didn't make the mesh a parent of the armature

Comment: great that you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Please don't write *solved* as part of the title. If you found a 
solution for your problem please write it on the 
answers section and mark it as accepted there. Read: 
[what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)